# python encoding ' (quotation) in xml file

Tags: python, xml, encoding, utf-8

I have a xml file for which the encoding information is not specified. I am trying to read it and write the file in another location using the below method

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree,html
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner,clean_html
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape, quoteattr
with open('check1.xml', 'rb') as file:
        xml_file = file.read()
tree = html.fromstring(xml_file)
tree1 = etree.ElementTree(tree)
tree1.write('path to XML file', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Input:

```
<unit>
 <source>Site name:  Investigation's address</source>
    <target></target>
</unit>
```

output:

```
<unit>&#13;
 <source>Site name: Investigationâsaddress </source>&#13;
    <target/>&#13;
</unit>&#13;
```

Why are these extra characters showing up and why does `'` not displayed properly.I tried latin-1 encoding but facing the similar issue except that for `'` different characters are displayed.

Comment: I execute your code using `python 2.7.12 and lxml-3.8.0` and it worked as expected. which version of `python`/ `lxml` are you using?

Comment: `&#13;` is a HTML coded character for `Carriage Return`. This is commonly escaped as `"\r"`, abbreviated CR, and has ASCII value 13 or 0x0D. Please check the `EOL` character in input file.

Comment: @Yaron : I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use `open()` to read XML files.** This is generally the wrong thing to do.

XML parsers have their own file handling. `ElementTree` is not an exception. Use `ET.parse()` to read files and `ET.write()`—or `tree.write()`—to write them.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('check1.xml')
tree.write('path to XML file', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

This simple parse-write cycle would also fix any messed-up line endings, since `\r\n` [is not a proper line ending in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends); it will always be converted to just `\n` automatically.

---

#### Background

In virtually all cases, the file handling functions in XML parsers properly deal with file encodings. Opening files yourself and reading them into strings breaks this automatic handling, i.e. doing this manually is a bug waiting to happen.

If the XML file is missing an XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..." ?>`) then it is assumed to be UTF-8. If such a file actually *isn't* UTF-8 for some reason, then it's, strictly speaking, broken.

XML-aware tools would not create such files. If you have such files, checking how they are created and fixing that process should be your first priority.

If that's not an option, trying to fix such a broken file is the *only* situation where reading the file into a string and giving that string to the XML parser would be the right solution. However, this requires prior knowledge of the file encoding, which is exactly the thing that you don't need to bother with when using `ET.parse()`.

Assuming the file is in [Windows Code Page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), erroneously misses the XML declaration, and you want to fix that by writing a properly encoded version:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('check1.xml', encoding="cp1252") as f:
    tree = ET.fromstring(f.read())

tree.write('path to XML file', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Unless you are in this very specific situation, use `ET.parse()` to read XML files.

Answer (score 1):

As DineshSuthar says, the problem is in your file line endings.

When you open file in binary mode, you cannot explicitly specify which newline should be used... and the parser gets confused.

If you know what newline separators your input file uses, you can use something like

```
xml_file = file.read().decode('utf-8').replace("\r\n","\n")
```

in your code to make it work.

Comment: Line endings in XML are `\n` as per the spec. `\r\n` is not used. See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends

Comment: @Tomlak that is possible and it may even be the source of this error. i ran the example code with the example input with various encoding and environment settings and the problem only shows up if the XML has wrong line endings (\r\n). my answer suggest how to fix the input.

Comment: String replacement on XML should be avoided, at the very least because you need to know the file encoding (UTF-8 is nothing but a guess, after all) and because more complex search/replace operations can easily destroy the file. A much better solution is to parse and write the file, since the parser fixes the line endings upon reading the file and the serializer writes a valid file, even pretty-printed, like the OP seems to want.

Comment: @Tomalak did you actually try to run the example code and reproduce the issue? the problem had nothing to do with encoding. described issue happens when the XML file has wrong line endings.

Comment: I know the issue has nothing to do with encodings. but reading XML files into strings does, so any answer that recommends doing that is inherently flawed. My answer goes into the details of this point because it is an important one and because too many people make that mistake.